# Unable to get property 'query' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, api

I am using [Yahoo Weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var callbackFunction = function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var location = data.query.results.channel.location;
    var condition = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
    var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind;
    var units = data.query.results.channel.units;

    document.getElementById('Weather-Info').innerHTML = 'The weather for ' + location.city + ', ' + location.region + ' is ' + condition.temp + units.temperature + ' with a wind speed of ' + wind.speed;
}
callbackFunction()
```

```
<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.forecast%20WHERE%20woeid%3D%222409681%22%20and%20u%3D%22f%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=callbackFunction"></script>
```

Everytime I go into the page I receive the following pop-up:

> Unable to get property 'query' of undefined or null reference

But if I hit No, the data is still populated.. how is it populating data if it is telling me that a property is undefined?  The YQL Weather API is a really complicated.

Comment: Notice that you are calling `callbackFunction` just after your definition. That is the reason why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling the callback function yourself? In any case, calling it without a parameter, means that `data` will be undefined and this is why you get the error.

I know nothing about Yahoo! weather API but this seems like a `JSONP` thing, so try removing this part:

```
callbackFunction()
```

since this will be called automatically once the script loads.